# Typescript type for React's useState() setter when

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, react-hooks

I'm trying to create React Context which parameters `mode` and `setMode` with are getter and setter of a React state. This is needed to be able to update the css mode (light / dark) from child components.

I'm getting this Typescript error for `value` of `ColorModeContext` (I guess, because this line of interface `AppContextInterface` is incorrect: `setMode:(c: string) => void)`:

[image: Error message]

```
function App() {

    interface AppContextInterface {
        mode: string;
        setMode:(c: string) => void
    }

    const ColorModeContext = React.createContext<AppContextInterface>({
        mode: 'dark', // set a default value
        setMode: () => {},
    })

    const [mode, setMode] = React.useState<PaletteMode>('dark');

    // Update the theme only if the mode changes
    const theme = React.useMemo(() => createTheme(getTheme(mode)), [mode]);

    return (
        <ColorModeContext.Provider value= {{ mode, setMode }}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <div>
                    </ChildComponent>
                </div>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </ColorModeContext.Provider>
    );
}
export default App;
```

How can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Since your `useState` type is defined as `PaletteMode` you need to define the same thing in your context's interface. In addition, you can also use the same types used to define the `setState` action (which you can import from React):

```
import { useState, createContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction} from 'react';

interface AppContextInterface {
  mode: PaletteMode;
  setMode: Dispatch<SetStateAction<PaletteMode>>
}

function App() {
  const ColorModeContext = createContext<AppContextInterface>({
      mode: 'dark', // set a default value
      setMode: () => {},
  })

  const [mode, setMode] = useState<PaletteMode>('dark');
```